# Model selection: testing accuracy higher than cross-validation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, cross-validation, validation

I trained convnets with different architetures and validated using 5-fold cross-validation. After this, I trained the final version of the convnets using the full data set (training + validation splits) and evaluated the performance on an external test set (i.e., not used before). This test set and the validation splits have almost the same number of samples, 416 vs 427.

The thing is the performance on the test set was higher (~10%) than the cross-validation performance. This happened for all architetures and even for a Random forest model I used as base line. I believe this is because I trained on much more data.

Do you think this is the case? And how can I make sure things are OK with my validation?
And how do I properly select the final algorithm to use, based on CV or testing? I believe it is based on CV, but I still confuse this, otherwise I would be leaking testing information into training.

Comment: Note that the sample size you trained on for the test set would have been 25% larger than any of the sample sizes you trained on for the cross-validation; assuming the test set was really representative of the data, we'd expect roughly $\sqrt(1.25) = 12\%$ better performance as a result, with a fair amount of variation possible due to having "only" ~400 samples for your performance calculations.

Comment: Yes this is normal, and indeed happens because you train on more data for the test versus the cross validation.